# Scale svg map regions on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an svg map. And I need to make the next thing:
When I'm hovering a region, it needs to be scaled. But I have an issue, some paths are still visible beneath the hovered region. You can see it when you hover bottom center region.
Tried to use z-index in css styles, but then found out that it won't work.
I'm free to use anything, to make it work
Thanks in advance)

```
[codepen]https://codepen.io/chegonenko/pen/gmoWWy
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style

```
path:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate about how this fixes the problem?  Honestly I can't really tell what the issue is, so I have no idea how you've improved it.

Comment: The section didnt scale up when it was hovered in your pen. 

You want to scale up each section on hover right?